# How to TakeSnapshot while streaming rtsp in a Xamarin form

Tags: xamarin.forms, libvlcsharp

I'm using libvlcsharp to stream camera, it working normally, but I can't take snapshot while stream is playing.

Here is my code :

```
 private void TakeScreenShot()
  {
    var folderPath = myServices.GetAppImageFolder();   
    var file = folderPath + "//abc.jpg"; 
    var file1 = Path.Combine(folderPath, "aabbc.jpg");
    MediaPlayer.TakeSnapshot(0,file,0,0);
    MediaPlayer.TakeSnapshot(0, file1, 0, 0);
    bool doesExist = File.Exists(file);
    bool doesExist1 = File.Exists(file1);
}
```

I can't find image, I tried use `MediaPlayer.SetVideoCallback(Lock,null,null)` too, but it crash before stream start play.

TakeSnapshot return true but:

- in Android, I can't find image in folder, doesExist = false.
- in iOS, doesExist = true , but I can't find folder contain image.

My folder path is `Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData`.

Comment: Like I said on gitlab, please provide full code in a git repo

Comment: @mfkl: if this is a cross-post, could you supply the link? I think it is healthy to discourage the cross-posting of questions, since without declaring the duplicates, it shows a question author is not taking care to avoid making duplicate work for volunteers.

Comment: https://code.videolan.org/videolan/LibVLCSharp/-/issues/393

Comment: https://github.com/ddoongvn/BlankApp2.
 This time it working perfectly, i don't know why last week i tried in 2 day and  not working, sorry